# How to use Django CSRF token correctly?

Tags: django

I followed the django doc about how to use the CSRF token. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/)

I understand the first two steps but I got confused on the step 3. In step 3, there are two options.

Option 1: UseRequestContext.

Option 2: Manually generate the CSRF token and add it to the template context.

If I want to use Option 1 and implement a view class from the base view class, do I need to do extra to generate the token?

Thanks.

Comment: It is already understood when you use csrf_token in your form. You don't have to put it in your view function. That views tutorial is another way to use csrf.

Comment: So if I use the csrf_token in the template and the csrf_protect decorator for the view, I should be good to go?

Comment: just use csrf token only in the template. django will recognize it

Comment: So in what situation I need to use the csrf_protect decorator?

Comment: csrf_token and csrf_protect decorator have similar function, just choose on them. In my opinion it better to use csrf_token in template, it pretty simple

Answer (score 9, accepted):

settings

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    //other middlewares

    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

]
```

template

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ......
</form>
```

views

```
def view_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        .....
```